# Express Js Mongoose not throwing Invalid Column error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

I am new to MongoDB and Express Js ecosystem. I am trying to setup a GraphQL Server using `express-graphql`. I have a very simple table called `Role` and it has two columns `role_name` and `role_description`. The table currently has only two roles, One is `SUPERADMIN` and the other is `USER`. When I try to make the below query, I get the correct GraphQL Response with the valid data.

```
Role.findOne({role_name: "SUPERADMIN"});
```

Whereas if I try to make the below query, I still get the same GraphQL Response. i.e. returns the `SUPERADMIN` row.

```
// There is no column called dummy_column in the roles table
Role.findOne({ role_name: "SUPERADMIN", dummy_column: "asd" });
```

Shouldn't the ORM / DB throw an error ? Even if it is not throwing an error, for invalid column, how is the same row (`SUPERADMIN`) returned ? Or Am I missing something ? Attached a gif of my issue.

[image: Screen Recording of the Issue]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a document-oriented database and there is no such term as **column** in MongoDB. MongoDB stores every entry as BSON (Binary JSON) document, and it actually doesn't care about schema so you can provide whatever you want. So it is expected that it won't throw an error for an invalid "column" because there is such thing as valid "columns" in MongoDB.

The validation may happen on the Mongoose level, if you need such a feature you can request it from the Mongoose team, maybe they will add it one day.

FWIW, there is a way to enforce MongoDB collection schema starting from 3.2 version. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

Comment: Thank You For your answer. As I am new to MongoDB, I am not fully aware of the Terminology. I can understand your point. I have edited my question. How is the same row returned ? Shouldn't it filter the records based on the filter ? Logically, the `SUPERADMIN`  row should not be returned right ?

Comment: Well it actually should, unless Mongoose discards all unknown fields :) 

Connect to MongoDB directly and run your query to see the results to check this idea.